# C - Encoding and decoding message using least significant bit

Tags: c, encryption, bit, unions

My task is to decode and encode message using least significant bit. Message is encrypted in least significant bits. To decode one letter I must check eight consecutive bytes(eight numbers). I must use bit field in union for this exercise. Decoding in my program works perfectly but I have problem with encoding.
Function encode doesn't encode anything. What is wrong with this function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

union bit_set
{
    signed char x;
    struct tab
    {
        unsigned char one: 1;
        unsigned char two: 1;
        unsigned char three: 1;
        unsigned char four: 1;
        unsigned char five: 1;
        unsigned char six: 1;
        unsigned char seven: 1;
        unsigned char eight: 1;
    } tab;
};

int decode(const char * array2, char *txt)
{
    union bit_set bit_set;
    
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while(*(array2 + i) != '\0')
    {
        signed char number = 0;
        for(int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
        {
            number = number << 1;
            
            bit_set.x = *(array2 + i);
            number = number + bit_set.tab.one;
            i++;
        }
        *(txt + j) = (char)number;
       
        if(*(txt+j) == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        j++;   
    }
    return 0;
}

int encode(const char *input, char *txt)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int len = strlen(input);
    
    while(j <= len)
    {
        union bit_set bit_set;
        bit_set.x = (signed char)*(input + j);
        for(int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
        {
            *(txt+i) &= 0xFE;
            *(txt+i) += bit_set.tab.eight;
            *(txt + i) <<= 1;
            
        }
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    int h = 0;
    while(h < 1000)
    {
        printf("%hhu ", *(txt + h));
        h++;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char msg[10000] = {0};
    char array[31] = "p"; //text for encode
    char array2[10000] = {100, 193, 113, 189, 184, 112, 148, 2, 244, 53, 97, 96, 100, 82, 96, 85, 64, 97, 97, 226, 56, 191, 217, 51, 76, 19, 155, 96, 236, 247, 10, 181, 
82, 42, 188, 4, 78, 178, 210, 86, 90, 110, 94}; //word 'page' for decode
    
    encode(array, msg);
    
    //decode(array2, msg);

    //printf("%s", msg);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the contents of `txt` is neither null-terminated (the `%s` format expects a null-terminated string), nor does the "characters" actually represent valid characters in the standard encoding used for your system (they're definitely not ASCII). If you need to print the values, you need to do so using a loop to print the actual values as integers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but if i print it as integers it prints me something like that: `0101010001101000011010010111001100100000011010010111001100100000011011010111100100100000011101000110010101111000011101` not normal numbers

Comment: You need to iterate over all the *bytes* in `txt` to print them one by one as decimal integers. Like `printf("%hhu ", txt[i])` for each valid index `i`. If the seemingly binary data is what you get from that, then you probably do the encoding wrong.

Comment: Some nitpicking: Why do you use e.g., `*(txt + j)` instead of `txt[h]` which is *exactly* the same, and easier to read and understand (not to mention less to write).

Comment: I edited my post with printing. I still see binary data only :( I see this numbers:  ` 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 ` Do you know what is wrong with encoding?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude in this exercise I must use pointers for printing instead of []

Comment: Time to break out your *debugger* and step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. As a hint: Are you sure that the `i++` is in the right place?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried to do this for 2 hours and I didn't find any errors, where I had to put i++? And my program still print binary data

Comment: The C standard does not define the order of bit fields, so the code you have is not assured of working with the least significant bit. To get the least significant bit of `x`, simply use `x&1`. To set it to `b`, use `x = x&~1 | b;`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil but my decoding function is working good

Comment: @ResCrove: Your C implementation may order bit fields in a way that works with your current source code. Some others will not. This code is not portable, and there is no reason for that. It is not a good way to write the code.

Comment: I need this code for tests. I am a student and I have to send my program to tests. Only in this form it can pass them. And that's why I know that decode function is good, beacuse it passed tests. I have got only big problem with encode I still don't know what's wrong with this

Comment: `bit_set.x <<= 1` can shift into the sign bit - UB.  Recommend `unsigned char x;`

Comment: "that's why I know that decode function is good, beacuse it passed tests." is a good first step, but even the `decode()` has weaknesses if not outright errors (UB).

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Much of the information you posted in comments should really be included in the question itself. Not to mention the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Lets take a look at the statements inside the inner loop:

```
*(txt+i) &= 0xFE;
*(txt+i) += bit_set.tab.eight;
bit_set.x <<= 1;
i++;
```

The first two statements will assign to `txt[i]`. The third doesn't matter for this problem. The fourth statement is the problem: You increase `i` so that next time you won't update the same index of `txt`, you be updating the next.

That leads to only a single bit being set for each element in `txt`.

The `i++` should probably be outside of the loop.

Comment: Some programmer dude, I edited my post, you think about something like that? It still don't working.

Comment: @ResCrove Please don't edit questions to incorporate answers. That will make the answers pointless, not to mention the question itself. Remember that this site is not only to help you right now, but also people in the future with the same or similar problems.

Comment: @ResCrove And can you tell me how it doesn't work now? What result do you get? What result did you expect? Have you tried to step through the code statement by statement in a debugger while monitoring variables and their values? Are you sure your algorithm is correct?

Comment: Yes i tried with a debugger, I am not sure my algorithm is correct, I received only zeros, but i expected (I must receive) this array `100, 193, 113, 189, 184, 112, 148, 2, 244, 53, 97, 96, 100, 82, 96, 85, 64, 97, 97, 226, 56, 191, 217, 51, 76, 19, 155, 96, 236, 247, 10, 181, 82, 42, 188, 4, 78, 178, 210, 86, 90, 110, 94`

Comment: @ResCrove Looking a little bit closer on the *decoding* part, which you claim to work fine, the encoding just doesn't seem to be the "opposite" of that. I can't really put my finger on it though, will see if I can get some time to look at it later. In the meantime I suggest you do the same.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I am sitting now and I will for few hours :)